# Get action on tap of Cancel in PKAddPassesViewController

Tags: ios, swift, wallet

I want Cancel action on PKAddPassesViewController to perform some validation but its delegate method addPassesViewControllerDidFinish does not have any property to differentiate between Cancel and AddAll action. Please help to identify which button is tapped to solve this mystery.

Comment: Can you please show some code?

Comment: func addPassesViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKAddPassesViewController) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true) {
            
        }
    }
In this method , I need to identify Cancel and AddAll button tap.

Comment: @AtalayAsa Don't know. Do you have any info about these?

Comment: Hi @MohitSinghal Sure this Link will help you!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068596/how-to-check-whether-cancel-or-add-button-is-pressed-in-pkaddpassesviewcontrolle

Comment: @Vicky_Vignesh I have checked this solution but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ? I know this is a Objective c !

please refer this [Link](http://qaru.site/questions/1140085/how-to-check-whether-cancel-or-add-button-is-pressed-in-pkaddpassesviewcontroller)

```
-(void) addPassesViewControllerDidFinish:(PKAddPassesViewController *)controller {

    if (self.HKPass) {
        PKPassLibrary *pkLibrary = [[PKPassLibrary alloc] init];
        if ([pkLibrary containsPass:self.HKPass]) 
                // add or update clicked
        else 
           // Cancel Clicked   

    }
    [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: It will not work on second time tap of Cancel button but its doable right now for my one of case but failed in other case. Thanks !!